# How to specify certain fields only in the query property

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a service which wraps requests to Elastic Search. This service only allows me to send the `query` property to Elastic Search. I want to tell Elastic Search to look only for matches in a certain field in a document.

For example, if this is my document:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  value: 'true'
}
```

Then I want to tell Elastic Search to look only for documents where `name` equals `foo`.

The Elastic Search [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting) says to do this by using the `fields` property like so:

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "this is a test",
    "fields" : [ "subject^3", "message" ] 
  }
}
```

But I can ONLY access the `query` property, so I can't specify `fields`. Lower down on the page, under [best fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields) it says that this is equivalent to doing something like `+first_name:will +first_name:smith`.  But when I put this, it's looking for text that actually matches `+first_name:will +first_name:smith` in the value, rather than looking for a `first_name` field that has a value `will`.

Is it possible to specify what field to search in with Elastic Search using only the `query` property?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect match for `query_string`(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). You can do something like this with it:

```
"query_string" : {
    "query" : "subject:whatever OR message:whatever"
  }
```

So, if you can change `multi_match` to `query_string` this would be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene supports fielded data. When performing a search you can either specify a field, or use the default field. The field names and default field is implementation specific.

You can search any field by typing the field name followed by a colon ":" and then the term you are looking for.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Name:\"foo bar cook\"",
            "default_operator" : "or"
        }
    }
}
```

use `default_operator` and to perform AND operation, or to perform OR kind of operation among the values